# IEnumerable<T> generics - "Cannot find symbol" inside method (T is passed by the calling function)

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, ienumerable

I'm trying to use IEnumerable generics. Im passing the data type from  another file while calling the corresponding method. But when using were to filter the IEnumerable i get the error "symbol not defined" since the IEnumerable method is passed during run time.

```
public IEnumerable<T> FetchData<T>(int take, int skip, string guidRelatedA, string guidRelatedB, bool filterA, bool filterB, IEnumerable<T> dataToFilter)
{
    if (filterA && filterB)
    {
        var  query = from p in dataToFilter
                     .Where(o => (o.FilterA.Any(f => f.Id.ToString().Equals(guidRelatedA))) &&
                                 (o.FilterB.Any(f => f.Id.ToString().Equals(guidRelatedB))))
                     .Take(take)
                     .Skip(skip)
                     select p;
        return query;
     } 
}
```

**FilterA** and **FilterB** throws me an error,FilterA and FilterB is common to all the classes im using, Is there any workaround to overcome this?

Comment: Can you guarantee that `T` will be a class that has properties named `FilterA` and `FilterB`?

Comment: As it is `T` could be absolutely anything. You need to use constraints to limit what `T` can be. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: in my pgm yes I can..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a constraint for T where T : base class or interface.

So something like

```
public interface IFilterable 
{
   object FilterA {get; set;}
   object FilterB {get; set;}
}

public IEnumerable<T> FetchData<T>(int take, int skip, string guidRelatedA, string guidRelatedB, bool filterA,
                             bool filterB, IEnumerable<T> dataToFilter) where T : IFilterable
{
...
}
```